# Moving from one activity to another while clicking tab

Tags: android

I am developing an application using `TabWidget`. I am getting an error (application is closed) while doing this code. The code given below is to move from `MainActivity` to `SecondActivity` while clicking `tab2`. Can anyone please help me?

```
tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
tabHost.setup();

spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Encryption");
spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
spec1.setIndicator("Encryption");

spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Decryption");
spec2.setIndicator("Decryption").setContent(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);//error in this line


tabHost.addTab(spec1);
tabHost.addTab(spec2);
```

Comment: Please post the error logs as well.

Comment: Avoid using TabHost as in above, its deprecated. Better use ActionBar with Tabs. It will be more fruitful for you in future.

Comment: @Ramya try my code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


        TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec"Encryption");
        spec1.setIndicator("Encryption");
        Intent Intent1 = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        spec1.setContent(Intent1);


        TabSpec spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Decryption");
        spec2.setIndicator("Decryption");
        Intent Intent2 = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        spec2.setContent(Intent2);


        tabHost.addTab(spec1); 
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
```

place these in main class , and in FirstActivity & SecondActivity place the two tab contents.

Add main, FirstActivity and ScondActivity in mainfest file.

Then try it works correctly. Update me wat happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to declare `SecondActivity` manifest.xml and you are getting `ActivityNotFound` or `ClassNotFound` exception. Add below line to maifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
```

Comment: I have declared SecondActivity in manifest.xml but still getting same error.